# Handle terminal window closing

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I'm currently working on an automation script that connects users via telnet to different ports (for different command interpreters) on an embedded system. Since the amount of available memory is pretty low on the system, the number of telnet sessions is limited. If a user doesn't close the telnet session normally, the server-side session will just hang and use up an available telnet session. Is there a way in tcl/expect to send commands/execute a procedure before an xterm window closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some googling, at it turns out `expect` supports the `trap` command which allows to run a script when a certain Unix signal is sent to the process hosting the interpreter.

It appears you have to trap `SIGHUP` but may be you'll also need to trap `SIGTERM` and/or `SIGQUIT`.  `man 7 signal` — if on a Linux-based OS — for more info (on a different OS flavor the manual page section may be different).